# When should Task.Run() be used?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, concurrency, task

What's the difference between these two approaches:

```
public static int Main(string[] args)
{
    string result;  

    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        Task<string> getStringTask = GetStringAsync();
        result = await validationsTask;
    }).Wait();

    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

and

```
public static int Main(string[] args)
{
    Task<string> getStringTask = GetStringAsync();
    getStringTask.Wait();
    string result = getStringTask.Result;

    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

I've seen a lot of people using the first approach and I'm not sure why. Is there any particular advantage? Which one is recommended for waiting async methods inside main of a Console Application?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any particular advantage?

Usually with `async` methods the operation is initialized synchronously and then the wait can be asynchronous with `await` or syncrhnous with `Wait()`. The `Main` method can't be `async` so you are force to block with `Wait()` there or you can do a `Console.ReadKey()` to run until the user presses a key.

`Task.Run(async () => ... )` can be quite useful when the `async` operation is expensive to initialize. That way you allow the main thread to continue while the operation is initializing.

> Which one is recommended for waiting async methods inside main of a Console Application?

I would use a slightly modified version of the second approach. You can add a `MainAsync` method and call that from `Main` then you can use `await` inside it.

```
public static async Task MainAsync()
{
    string result = await GetStringAsync();    
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}

public static int Main(string[] args)
{
    MainAsync().Wait();
}
```

Also with console apps there is no risk of deadlock as there is no `SynchronizationContext` and the default thread pool one gets used.

Answer (score 0):

The first approach continues execution after the asynch function is finished using a thread pool thread while the second approach continues execution using the calling thread that starts the asynch function.

With the second approach, there is a possibility of deadlocks. For example (similar to an example extracted from the book [CLR via C#)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735667454):

```
    public static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task<string> getStringTask = GetStringAsync();
        string result = getStringTask.Result; //the main thread is blocked waiting.

        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }

    public Task<string> GetStringAsync()
    {  
        // Issue the HTTP request and let the thread return from GetHttp 
        HttpResponseMessage msg = await new HttpClient().GetAsync("http://Wintellect.com/"); 
        // We never get here: The main thread is waiting for this method to finish but this method 
        // can't finish because the main thread is waiting for it to finish --> DEADLOCK! 
        return await msg.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
```

So the first approach avoids this problem:

```
public static int Main(string[] args)
{
    string result;  

    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        // We run on a thread pool thread
        Task<string> getStringTask = GetStringAsync();
        // We do get here because any thread pool thread can execute this code, we don't need the main thread.
        result = await validationsTask;
    }).Wait();

    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Another solution is using [ConfigureAwait](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.configureawait(v=vs.110).aspx)(false), extracted from the book:

> Passing true to this method gives you the same behavior as not calling
>   the method at all. But, if  you pass false, the await operator does
>   not query the calling thread’s SynchronizationContext object and, when
>   a thread pool thread completes theTask, it simply completes it and the
>   code after  the await operator executes via the thread pool thread.

```
    public Task<string> GetStringAsync()
    {  
         HttpResponseMessage msg = await new HttpClient().GetAsync("http://Wintellect.com/").ConfigureAwait(false); 
         // We DO get here now because a thread pool can execute this code 
// as opposed to forcing the main thread to execute it.   
         return await msg.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
```